# calls not as expected for didEndContact function of SCNPhysicsContactDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, game-physics, scenekit

I'm trying to detect and manage collisions between a sphere (with a Kinematic body) and a cube (with a static body). Both nodes have physic shapes based on primitives.

For test purposes, I move the sphereNode just onto the surface of the cube, and my function didBeginContact is called as expected.

Now if I lift my sphere by 0.1, my function didEndContact is also called as expected. But if instead I lift it by 0.2 or more, didEndContact is never called.

Same happens when I make the sphere and box intersects. If I move my sphere either way by 0.1 only the didUpdateContact is called (as expected). But if I move it by 0.2 then didEndContact is called just before didBeginContact is called again. My sphere never stopped intersecting the box.

Those results depends on the translation distance of the sphere per frame, but also on the sphere radius.

Does anyone have an idea why SCNPhysicsContact has this behavious?